# Как сделать счетчик уведомлений как в ios на иконке приложения?

Tags: android

Как сделать счетчик уведомлений как в ios на иконке приложения, есть какое нибудь решение для android?

Comment: Notification Badge (API 26) https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

Comment: так же нужно учитывать, что до android 8 такой функциональности в апи андроид не было. были решения для конкретных лончеров (как Nova Launcher) или оболочек (например от самсунг), каждое решение имело свои механизмы реализации и ни о каком универсальном коде речи не шло.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже писали в комментариях, есть Notification Badge - который работает с апи версии 26. Если нужно поддержка более ранних версий - можно воспользоваться библиотекой: [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

Comment: А есть примеры работы с библиотекой ShortcutBadger? может я ее неправильно использую, но у меня не добавляется счетчик на иконку

Answer (score 0):

Нашел реализацию для данных устройств в исходниках телеграмма https://tlgrm.ru/sources 
класс org.telegram.messenger.NotificationBadge
[image: Поддерживаемые устройства и лаунчеры]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа